# How to properly close Google Api Client MediaHttpUploader

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm uploading a file use `Google Api Java Client` `Drive` service. I can't find how to close the streams.

```
final FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, new java.io.File(data));
final Drive.Files.Insert insert = mDriveService.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
final MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

final File file = insert.execute();
```

Eventually throwing Strict Mode error

```
A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
at com.google.api.client.http.FileContent.getInputStream(FileContent.java:71)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:397)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.mypackage.MyClass.myMethod(line)
```

Comment: The input stream should be closed automatically by the client library (see [MediaHttpUploader.java#425](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/media/MediaHttpUploader.java?name=1.18.0-rc#425)). Can you check the value of `mediaContent.getCloseInputStream()` in your code?

Comment: @EricKoleda pretty strange, the error is not printed anymore. Though I'm testing on different device today. It must be a device bug that prints warning. `mediaContent.getCloseInputStream()` should be false because I haven't explicitly set it to true.